# Issues creating a card that shows a description when mouse over using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am trying to make cards that show a description when you mouse over them. I have made this so far: https://jsfiddle.net/L0xsug1o/. The code is also added to the end of the post

There are two things I'm stuck on:

1. How do I add a div to that white space that appears when you mouse over, such that it's hidden when you're not moused over? Anything I try is visible when the mouse isn't over the card.
2. How do I made the widths of the images not decrease as they animate out?

These issues are related in a way as they both involve creating divs that can slide in and out of view.

I am using Google's Material Design Lite frontend framework

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

CSS:

```
.mdl-card{
    height: 275px;
}

.mdl-card__media {

  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: flex-grow 0.25s;
  transition: flex-grow 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);;

}

.mdl-cell:hover .mdl-card__media, .mdl-cell.hover .mdl-card__media {
    -webkit-transition: flex-grow 0.3s; /* Safari */
    transition: flex-grow 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    flex-grow: 0;
}

#nyc{
    background-image: url('http://com.postmates.img.prod.s3.amazonaws.com/9fcb0858-0759-4e78-874b-bdcc2a048181/orig.jpg');
}
#hkg{
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Hong_Kong_Island_Skyline_2009.jpg/1200px-Hong_Kong_Island_Skyline_2009.jpg');
}
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:200,300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue_grey-blue.min.css" />
<div class="project-holder mdl-grid">
  <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__media" id="nyc"></div>
    <div class="mdl-card__title">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">New York City</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__media" id="hkg"></div>
    <div class="mdl-card__title">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Hong Kong</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0xsug1o/1/)

Comment: This breaks the animation though. I am trying to stick to material design principles. Is there an way to retain the animation, but simply have some text in the white space that appears?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. I don't want the title (e.g. New york city) to be hidden when the card is not moused over. I want a description, which is not shown in the js fiddle, to be visible in the empty space you see when you mouse over, but hidden when you are not moused over

Comment: If this is close to what you asked for let me, i will fix the animation and make a answer of it, and there is no description in your HTML content

Comment: Let me make another js fiddle that shows what I want it to look like when moused over since it seems maybe I am not describing it clearly

Comment: Okay, so in this fiddle, the second card is stuck on what I want it to look like when a card is moused over https://jsfiddle.net/L0xsug1o/2/ I want the text to animate up with the title coming out from the bottom of the card

Answer (score 1):

> There are two things I'm stuck on:
>
> 1. How do I add a div to that white space that appears when you mouse
>      over, such that it's hidden when you're not moused over? Anything I
>      try is visible when the mouse isn't over the card.
> 2. How do I made the widths of the images not decrease as they animate
>      out?

1. You might animate `max-height` of the div with the text.
2. This can be solved using `background-size` property, but keep in mind that aspect ratio of the images is the most important part of this issue. So I'd suggest to have images with the same aspect ratio to handle them easily.

```css
.mdl-card {
  height: 275px;
}

.project .mdl-card__supporting-text {
  max-height: 0px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.25s;
  transition: max-height 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
}

.mdl-cell:hover .mdl-card__supporting-text {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.mdl-card__media {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: flex-grow 0.25s;
  transition: flex-grow 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 1, 1);
}

.mdl-cell:hover .mdl-card__media,
.mdl-cell.hover .mdl-card__media {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

#nyc {
  background-size: 220% auto;
  background-image: url(https://www.newyorksocialnetwork.com/wp-content/gallery/welcome/nyc-skyline_web.jpg);
}

#hkg {
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-image: url(https://news.efinancialcareers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/HK2.jpg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue_grey-blue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="project-holder mdl-grid">
  <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__media" id="nyc"></div>
    <div class="mdl-card__title">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">New York City</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
      Hong Kong, officially the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region of the People's Republic of China, is an autonomous territory on the eastern side of the Pearl River estuary in East Asia, south of the mainland Chinese province of Guangdong, and east
      of the former Portuguese colony and fellow special administrative region of Macau.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__media" id="hkg"></div>
    <div class="mdl-card__title">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Hong Kong</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
      Hong Kong, officially the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region of the People's Republic of China, is an autonomous territory on the eastern side of the Pearl River estuary in East Asia, south of the mainland Chinese province of Guangdong, and east
      of the former Portuguese colony and fellow special administrative region of Macau.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The size of the three divs doesn't equal the size of the card in this. This gives the appearance of the text appearing out of the middle of the card. See this screenshot I took mid-animation to see what I mean https://i.imgur.com/OP3Qgr8.png

Comment: Cannot reproduce.